# Kafka getting data as base64 encoded strings even though Producer does not explictly encode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm new to Kafka. I am trying out a simple example to publish data from Kafka and consume it using Spark.

Here is the code:

```
df = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",'endpoint_link_here') \
.option("subscribe", "Topic_1") \
.load()

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df1 = df.select(col("key").cast("string"),col("value").cast("string"))
```

The data I received is in this format, i want to get the data in readable format.

[image]

```
n��͡����! hello hey city"  dinsk TEST"  country TEST"  band 
dddf*�dsimJ
```

Comment: show how do you write data into Kafka

Comment: We are getting the data from client. Don't know much details about it @AlexOtt

Comment: Usually you need to have a kind of "contract" that describes how data is encoded. In Kafka, everything is just array of bytes, but you need to have an agreement between producer & consumer how the actual data is encoded to that byte arrays

Answer (score 1):

Data shown in not "base64". It is encoded, yes, maybe even encrypted, but your terminal will display base64 in actual ASCII symbols.

Without knowing how your data was initially serialized, you cannot blindly deserialize into strings.